# LogMel Spectrogram

Tags: neural-network

I just can't wrap around my head on the concept pertaining LogMel Spectrogram in this CRNN model. I want to integrate it on a thesis I am writing on Using EEG-Based Drowsiness Detecting Helmet. This is suppose to be my RRL as I was trying to find ways to improve the accuracy of my data.

This is the link: https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/neuroscience/articles/10.3389/fnins.2023.1136609/full#B25